# How do I fix this error when coding my new bot?

Tags: python, discord, bots, helper

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=".", intents=intents)
NameError: name 'commands' is not defined

```

I follow the code on the youtube but an error occurred and idk how to fix this?
[image]

I am need to code a bot and I'm learning Python basic

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial is outdated. It's for discord.js v12 I think. They are using v14 now. V12 is no longer supported.

Comment: So how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You have already imported everything from the `commands` module, so just say `bot = Bot(..)`

Comment: And a error occured that there were no such a command named "Bot" in discord ;-;

Answer (score -1):

Ah, sorry, i thought you were using discord.js but turns out you use python, lol. Just try using a newer tutorial: https://youtu.be/hoDLj0IzZMU